# To show $\int_{[-2,2]} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} d \mu \to 2$ using convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. Then use convergence theorem to evaluate :

$(1)$ To show $\int_{[0,\pi/2]} (\sin x)^n d \mu \to 0$,

$(2)$ To show $\int_{[-2,2]} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} d \mu \to 2$.

**Answer:**

$(1)$  For $0 \leq x < \pi/2$, we have $ 0 \leq \sin x <1$, and so $(\sin x)^n \to 0$ while for $x=\pi/2$, we have $\sin (\pi/2)=1$.

Thus $\int_{[0,\pi/2]} (\sin x)^n d \mu=\int_{[0,1)} (\sin x)^n d \mu+ \int_{\{\frac{\pi}{2}\}} (\sin x)^n d \mu=0+\mu (\{\frac{\pi}{2}\})=0+0=0$.

How to prove the 2nd one ?

$\int_{[-2,2]} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} d \mu=2 \int_{[0,2]} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} d \mu=2 \leq \int_{[0,2]} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} d \mu=2 \mu([0,2])=4 $  but we have to show $2$.

Help me

Comment: You forgot the limits in the initial question.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, yes thanks. Can you look at 2nd question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is the last part  of that line : $\int_{0}^2 \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} d \mu \not \to \mu([0,2])$, because you have to be careful about the pointwise limit.

---

In question $2$, DCT applies since the (absolute value of the) given function is uniformly bounded by $1$. Hence, we need to look at the limit as $n \to \infty$ of $\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$. Note that if $|x|<1$ then this limit is $0$ as $x^{2n} \to 0$, and if $|x| > 1$ this limit is $1$ as $x^{2n} \to \infty$. Of course, $|x|=1$ is a set of measure zero, hence ignored.

Therefore, the pointwise limit of the functions $\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ is(upto the set of measure zero) :
$$
f(x) =\begin{cases}
0 & |x| <1\\
1 & |x| > 1
\end{cases}
$$
therefore the answer is the measure of $[-2,2] \cap \{|x| >1\} = [1,2] \cap [-1,-2] = 2$. You got this question wrong by exactly half because you thought the whole function converges to $1$ so the answer is the entire measure of $[-2,2]$ which is twice the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome, @Masmath